# Messed Up Reg Key: Software\Classes\ms-settings\shell\open\command

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I ran a python program that messed up this registry key: `Software\Classes\ms-settings\shell\open\command`.

What would be the default value of `(default)` and `DelegateExecute`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(default)` is empty -- i.e., value not set.
`DelegateExecute` is `{4ed3a719-cea8-4bd9-910d-e252f997afc2}`
[image]
(Windows 10 20H2 registry screenshot)

Comment: is the `DelegateExecute` always this value, or does it change between computers?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor: The `DelegateExecute` value data for the specified key doesn't change from system to system. It's always the same.